# Can I use a non-injected field in the constructor of a stateless EJB?

Tags: jakarta-ee, ejb, stateless

Is it Java EE compliant to have an empty constructor in a stateless EJB using a non-injected field as in the example?

```
@WebService
@Stateless
@SOAPBinding(...)
@RunAs(...)
public class ParameterWebservice {

   @EJB
   private PService pService;

   private final Set<PrivacyO> allowed;

   public ParameterWebservice() {
      allowed= new HashSet<>();
      allowed.add(PrivacyO.EXPOSE_THROUGH_LAYER_A);
      allowed.add(PrivacyO.EXPOSE_THROUGH_LAYER_B);
   }

   ...
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it Java EE compliant to have an empty constructor in a stateless EJB...

Yes, the ejb 3.1 [specification](http://download.oracle.com/otndocs/jcp/ejb-3.1-pfd-oth-JSpec/) says:

> 4.9.2 Session Bean Class
>
> ... • The class must have a public constructor that takes no parameters. The container uses this
> constructor to create instances of the session bean class. ...

Comment: I agree. As a word of caution, the spec makes no guarantee about the thread contexts when the constructor is called, so doing anything in a constructor related to java:comp, context class loader, security, transaction, etc. is probably unportable, so it would be best to move that logic to `@PostConstruct`.

Comment: Thanks for the answers. Finally, I opted for a cleaner implementation. I moved inside the enum the logic that checks if it is allowed or not and therefore I can supress the allowed variable from the webservice.